# What is the double point on the filterbar?

Tags: sapui5

I have a filterbar that looks as following:

```xml
<fb:FilterBar>
  <fb:filterGroupItems>
    <fb:FilterGroupItem
      groupName="sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar.INTERNAL_GROUP"
      name="Basic"
      visibleInFilterBar="true"
    >
      <fb:control>
        <DatePicker/>
      </fb:control>
    </fb:FilterGroupItem>
  </fb:filterGroupItems>
</fb:FilterBar>
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, there is a double point. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't used FilterGroupItem before, but a colon usually indicates that there must be Label similar to how `sap.ui.layout.form.(Simple)Form` behaves.

According to the [API reference](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterGroupItem/), the Item can contain `groupTitle` and `label`. Try to assign values to those properties.